# Binding trigger on multiple Pikoday calendar pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar, pikaday

Okay, so I have some input fields on a page. I need to add a datepicker to those. And I have to use the tiny calendar icon next to the input field itself.

Im using Pikaday for my calendar, and one apply a trigger element. However, it doesn't seem to work. As you can see from my code below, I'm finding the relevant datepicker-button-element, and I'm using that as my trigger.

Expected result:
http://dbushell.github.io/Pikaday/examples/trigger.html

HTML:

```
<div class="datepicker-able">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker number1"> 
     <a href="#" class="datepicker-button">button1</a>
</div>

<div class="datepicker-able">
    <input type="text" class="datepicker number2"> 
     <span class="datepicker-button">button2</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).pikaday({
            field: element,
            trigger: $(element).closest('div').find('.datepicker-button').get(0), // <<<<
            firstDay: 1,
            //position: 'top right',
            minDate: new Date('1900-01-01'),
            maxDate: new Date('2015-10-15'),
            format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
            defaultDate: new Date('1980-01-01'),
            yearRange: [1900,2020],
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you include all the relevant JS includes?

Comment: Yes. When I comment out the "trigger", the calendar works as expected... That is when input field is focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you may have problems with one of the includes, may be an old version of pikaday is being used/the order of includes as it works fine when I try it. Also, since you know that the trigger button is right next to the input, you may use the `.next()` selector.

Take a look at the working example below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.datepicker').each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).pikaday({
            field: element,
            trigger: $(element).next('.datepicker-button')[0],
            firstDay: 1,
            //position: 'top right',
            minDate: new Date('1900-01-01'),
            maxDate: new Date('2015-10-15'),
            format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
            defaultDate: new Date('1980-01-01'),
            yearRange: [1900,2020],
        });
    });
});
```

Here is [a fiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73xLwjmf/) the same!

Comment: You were right. I downloaded the lastest versions of "everything" and that fixed it. When it comes to `next()`, the datepicker button is not always next to the input, so I have to use the parent just to be sure.

Comment: Glad you sorted it. Good luck!

Comment: And this is beside the question, but do you see a way to have a trigger on input field focus as well as a button click?